# transfering from international to domestic flight at IAD - Dulles airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, connecting-flights, iad

I will be flying from Viennna, Austria to Dulles and then to Savannah.
Our flight from Vienna is operated by Austrian airlines and will arrive a B-gates. Our flight to Savannah is operated by United and will be leaving from D-gates.
I am traveling alone with my son so I will have a stroller that makes it a bit slower/harder to get around.
I am reading different things on different websites and wondering if anyone could advice me how to get from B to D. I know we will have to go through immigration and customs and even collect our luggage and re-check them. Will we have to go through security again? Where is immigration located?

Connected question, but this time we travel the other direction: [Connecting flight at IAD Dulles with stroller](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/160948/connecting-flight-at-iad-dulles-with-stroller)

Comment: At US airports, you pretty much always have to go through security after customs.  The idea is that you have had access to your checked luggage, which might contain items you are not allowed to carry on.

Comment: Also, the US / the TSA has only limited trust in the quality of security checks done on foreign ground - after all, they are not done by TSA. Even though they are often more thorough / picky.

Answer (score 3):

At IAD airport, moving between terminals isn’t a big task. After you land, you will take a inter terminal bus (looks like a bus but is actually a vehicle with big wheels that can attach directly to a special gate at the airport so you can just walk in directly) to the main immigration hall. The immigration hall immediately exits into the baggage claim area where you will collect your luggage, go to the departures level right above, recheck everything in, go through the security and then take a train to your connecting terminal. More info can be found at https://www.flydulles.com/iad/international-arrivals

Comment: thank you! I looked at their website and studied the map. Would you possibly know how I will get to the upper level to re-check our bags?

Comment: I believe there’s an elevator but if not just two flights of escalators.

Comment: Whilst this answer is correct for the question asked, it's worth pointing out that the process varies depending on the airline. Specifically, for United arrivals there is a separate immigration facility for connecting passengers and you do not go through the steps listed above but instead pass through immigration/baggage collection/bag drop/security in a dedicated "midfield" terminal which then lets you out directly into terminal C.

Comment: Don't forget the security check before your second flight. It took me 10 mins on October 29, around 4 pm.